# get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to_date'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to filter the users that are created between certain dates, I am using the filter method. But i am having a problem passing the arguments, how can i pass the argument in a correct fashion, this is what i have tried so far.

views.py

```
class RegisteredUserFilter(APIView):
    serializer = RegisteredUserFilterSerializer
    
    def get(self, from_date, to_date):
        userondate = User.objects.filter(created_at__range=[from_date, to_date]).values()
        users = []
        for user in userondate:
            users.append(user['username'])
        return Response({"User": users})
```

serialzers.py

```
class RegisteredUserFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
from_date = serializers.DateField()
to_date = serializers.DateField()
model = User
```

full code here: https://github.com/abinashkarki/rest_framework_authentication/tree/master/authapp

while doing this i am getting:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to_date'
```

How should the argument be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to take args from `get`, u have to write it in your urlpattern.
So, u have to write something like

```
path('userRegisteredOnDate/<from_date>/<to_date>/', RegisteredUserFilter.as_view()),
```

like in your **password-reset** urlpattern.
And then you should parse it, because method will takes string type, not date type.

Comment: If u want to take args not from url keywords but from url parameters like `?username=max`, your code will be like `from_date = self.request.GET['from_date']`.

Comment: I tried from_date = self.request.GET['from_date'] like this but still am getting the same error message

Comment: @AbinashKarki You need to delete `from_date` and `to_date` args from `get` method.